# English related question about quantization and separation of variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology

I'm not a native speaker, and this question is about "how to say it in English".
Consider a 2D electronic waveguide. Wavefunction $\psi(x,y)$ can be written in form of separated variables $\psi(x,y)=U(x)V(y)$.
Now we add boundary conditions related to $y$-axis. Spectrum of $V(y)$ becomes discrete with energies $E_n$.
How to describe this in English? Can I say "$y$-quantization" about the operation I do, and "$n$ is a $y$-quantum number" about the $n$?

Comment: I guess we would say that the $E_n$ are the energy eigenvalues.

Comment: I would write $n_y$ to indicate that it is a quantum number associated with the $y$-direction.